# Second maximum value by using dense rank function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have table like:

```
name     marks
raja     88
ravi     88
karthik  99
praveen  99
vijay    70
```

In that table I assume the rank of the table is:

```
name      marks        rank 
karthirk    99           1
praveen     99           2
raja        88           3
ravi        88           4
vijay       77           5
```

I get that by using `dense rank()` function:

```
select  name,marks,dense_rank() over(  order by name ) as ranks
from std_D_D order by marks desc
```

but what I need is from that above table I need to get second lowest rank. 
I mean the output  I want is:

```
ravi 88   4
```

I tried to get the second lowest rank but I can't get the all the columns. I tried this query:

```
select max(a.ranks) as b from (
select  name,marks,dense_rank() over(  order by name ) as ranks
from std_D_D ) as a where a.ranks not in
(

select max(a.ranks) as b from (
select  name,marks,dense_rank() over(  order by name ) as ranks
from std_D_D ) as a )
```

Comment: if you use `DENSE_RANK()` you'll get the same rank for people with the same marks, which is not same as your assumed rank.

Comment: Do you want to 2nd lowest `marks` or `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aswer for my above question :

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT NAME,MARKS,dense_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY RANK DESC,name) AS TEMP_ORDER FROM

(SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY MARKS DESC,NAME) AS RANK FROM std_D_D) A
) B WHERE TEMP_ORDER=2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could reverse the ranking order and select the second one:

```
SELECT name, marks
FROM   (SELECT name, makrs, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name DESC) AS ranks
        FROM   std_D_D) t
WHERE  ranks = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and one more doubt is is that same thing possible  using join function or else some other functions ?

Comment: Thanks @ughai , i want to get the second minimum rank ,that means 4th rank out of 5 rank . from that above table i need to return the values praveen  99   4 using this dense_rank() function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dhamodharan yes, of course - you can go on and add additional function calls, joins, etc to this query

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that if you use `DENSE_RANK()` you'll get the same rank for people with the same marks, which is not same as your assumed rank.

**EDIT**

Based on OP's comment, added additional `ORDER BY name DESC`.

**Sample Data**

```
DECLARE @std_D_D table
(
name VARCHAR(10),
marks int
)

insert into @std_D_D values
('raja',    88),
('ravi',    88),
('karthik',  99),
('praveen',  99),
('vijay',    70);
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT name,marks,dense_rank() over(ORDER BY marks ASC,name DESC) as ranks
from @std_D_D
)
SELECT name,marks,ranks
FROM CTE
WHERE ranks = 2
```

Output of this query will give you

```
ravi    88  2
```

Comment: i will explain my concept first , i want to give a dense_rank for all students, if two students have same mark ,i will give rank based on their names ,for this scenario i want to get the second minimum rank that means 4th rank values out of 5 ranks.

Comment: so from that i want to get the fourth rank  persons value ,
that means i want to return the row   "  ravi 88 4 " this is the second last lask in my table.
 hope this enough for you to get my point. Thanks

Comment: @Dhamodharan,  In your question you want `praveen  99`, here you want `ravi 88`. Do you know what do you want?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri  - I guess what OP really needs is `ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY marks ASC, name )` where name can be ordered `ASC` or `DESC`

Comment: @gioNakeri , Already --ughai answerd my first query  ,Now i want to find the values of second lowest rank (i.e) values for rank 4 ,because that only the second lowest rank .

Comment: @Dhamodharan, with ughai's first question you get `praveen 99 4`. 4 rank belongs to praveeen. So again do you want praveeeen or ravi? Oh my gosh...

Comment: @Dhamodharan - just to clear the confusion, you want to sort students based on marks with highest marks as rank 1 and so on. if the marks are same for 2 or more students, then higher priority should be given based on name in ascending order. Based on this ranking you now want to know the second last person based on such ranking which would be `ravi`

Comment: @ughai ,yes that is what my requirement but if 2 or more students, then higher priority should be given based on name in ascending order (ex)
name  marks ,aab 80,aaa 80  i will give rank aaa 80 1 ,aab 80 2 .

Comment: Please update the ranks and the expected output in your question so its perfectly clear to everyone who looks at the question and the related answers. my updated answer should help you out

Comment: `aab 80,aaa 80 i will give rank aaa 80 1 ,aab 80 2` lool, this ranking will give you `raja 88`. This is epic.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - `aaa` will get higher rank = 1 (should be treated as having more marks) so aab will be at the bottom. so our inverse rank will have `ORDER BY marks ASC,name DESC`

Comment: @ughai , --giorgi hai both ,thanks for ur help i got the answer by myself 

SELECT * FROM
(SELECT NAME,MARKS,dense_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY RANK DESC,name) AS TEMP_ORDER FROM
(SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY MARKS DESC,NAME) AS RANK FROM std_D_D)A)B
WHERE TEMP_ORDER=2

Comment: we'll your query is essentially a `dense_rank() over(ORDER BY marks ASC,name DESC)` as all the ranking is done by `DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY MARKS DESC,NAME)` and you just inverse it in the following `DENSE_RANK()`. Great that you got the answer yourself. I hope the question can now be marked as closed.

Comment: @ughai Yup ,i will close this query .Thank u both . :-)